# php null is undefined value?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I got error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: null

Line in code is:

```
$input = new $class($company, null, $sablonas, $null, $value);
```

Class constructor is:

```
public function __construct($company, $document, $sablonas, $options, $value = null) {
```

How I can pass a *null* value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$input = new $class($company, null, $sablonas, $null, $value);
//                             ^                 ^
//                            (1)               (2)
```

It's talking about `(2)`, not `(1)`. You have a typo with `$null`.

---

The notice message "Undefined variable: null" is a little misleading here, but consider the following case:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
echo $lol;
// Output: "Notice: Undefined variable: lol in /t.php on line 3"
?>
```

You can see that the `$` isn't included in the name that the notice message gives you, so if you follow this logic back you arrive at the conclusion I made at the top of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have `$null` as a variable:

```
$input = new $class($company, null, $sablonas, $null, $value);
//------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^

// Guessing that's supposed to be
$input = new $class($company, null, $sablonas, null, $value);
//-------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$null = NULL;
```

Comment: The minimum character requirement is there to encourage you to write actual words and sentences in answers, not to write arbitrary fluff to subvert it. Seems obvious.

Comment: The question was `How I can pass a null value?`, it is 28 characters, so I answered in the same manner...

Comment: It seems you've missed my point.

Comment: I disagree that you need more words, but you could be more subtle about it.